# The toogle js class not changing the Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have tried this toggle js to change the icon on click but its not happening. What am I doing wrong here.

Here's the html

```
<div class="south-search-form">
 <form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for Ballet, Jazz, Policies ...">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
 </form>
</div>

<!-- Search Button -->
<a href="#" class="searchbtn" style="font-size: 20px;">
<i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Here's the Js

```
  var searchbtnI = $(".searchbtn i");
  var searchbtn = $(".searchbtn");

  searchbtnI.addClass('fa-search');
  searchbtn.on('click', function () {
      $("body").toggleClass('search-close');
      searchbtnI.toggleClass('fa-times');
  });
```

So, If you observe this line `<i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>` within the `<a>` tag, I know that this tag has to be updated to "X" with toogleClass in js. But what Im observing here is, for some weird reason the `<i>` tag is being commented when I inspect the element on my website for which is why it is not changing to other icon. Why is this even happein?

Here my website:- https://dancestudiov2.herokuapp.com/homenew
You can check the header with the search icon on the right most and inspect it to get what I'm talking about. 
Ill highly appreciate your input.

Thank you

Comment: Try to use `font awesome`` CSS` files not `JS` , and you can use `addClass` and `removeClass` .

Comment: I am already using font awesome. Also can you be specfic or give a solution rather.

Comment: I mean that font-awesome **.js**  convert the icon into `SVG` , that's why your selector cannot find the `i` element , try to remove the `JS` files and use only `CSS` files , this could be the solution.

Comment: Ok thank you. let me try it

Comment: Im being using     ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">``` and if you observe the svg is also there. Ive all used add Class and removeClass but again no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code snippet, i'm using your code without any changes, the icon does not changed to `SVG` because i'm using only font-awesome CSS file, check your code for font-awesome JS library and remove it, you will find this line in your html :

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
var searchbtnI = $(".searchbtn i");
  var searchbtn = $(".searchbtn");

  searchbtnI.addClass('fa-search');
  searchbtn.on('click', function () {
      $("body").toggleClass('search-close');
      searchbtnI.toggleClass('fa-times');
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="south-search-form">
 <form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for Ballet, Jazz, Policies ...">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
 </form>
</div>

<!-- Search Button -->
<a href="#" class="searchbtn" style="font-size: 20px;">
<i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: By the way, you have a lot of duplication in your code, this will case many errors, for example the jQuery library duplicated 3 times `<script src="/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Its working perfectly.

Comment: thank you for the duplication. ive removed it and will see if further duplication is there. Also when I removed the line ```<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 ``` all the other fontawesome icons are gone which is using the class ```fas``` so ive come to know that ive to make all of them to ```fa``` in order to bring them back.

Comment: The class `fas` is for font-awesome 5 and above, you are using font-awesome 4.7 CSS files, use this instead `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">` and change old font-awesome 4.7 classes. Also dont duplicate the `id's` of divs.

Comment: Here is a [list of available icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free).

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and all the other icons are back. Highly appreciate your time and your wonderfull help